# How do you loop through text file in C/AL(Navision)

Tags: navision

I am trying to create a function that will parse through a text file that has two columns: customer number and file address. As the function loops through each record in the text file, have it search for a Customer record based upon the first column, and if found, insert a record link whose URL is the value of the file address column. I am using Microsoft Dynamics NAV so it involves C/AL. any insights would be much appreciated since I cannot seem to find what I want when I google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

```
//variable:
//Name: recDir, DataType: Record,    Subtype: File(2000000022)
//Name: txtPath, DataType: Text, Length: 100
//coding:
txtPath:='C:\temp\';
recDir.RESET;
recDir.SETRANGE(Path,txtPath);
recDir.SETRANGE("Is a file",TRUE);
IF recDir.FIND('-') THEN BEGIN
    REPEAT 
        MESSAGE('%1',recDir.Name); 
     UNTIL recDir.NEXT=0;
END;
```